# What does "Per [person's name]" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, vocabulary

What does "Per John:" mean?

From the context of the article I'm reading (article unlinked), it seems to mean "From John:" or "John (said):"

What exactly does the word "per" mean when used as such?

Comment: Can you please provide more context? I'd like to give my answer but I wanna be sure from where you took that expression. :)

Comment: A colleague of mine has the first name "Per." So, it'll be "Per per" in his case ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of 'as per'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30781/usage-of-as-per)

Comment: @aedia this is a totally different thing altogether. My question is having the Per at the start of the sentence, with the syntax: 
"Per [name]:"

Comment: I suggested that these are the same because the meaning doesn't change if we write *per* or *as per* someone. If, in a cover message, I write, *As per John: Title changed to "Exceedingly Boring Report"* or *Per John: Title changed to "Exceedingly Boring Report"*, there's really no difference; I am saying the title was changed *according to* John. The new title came from him, or the change was made on account of his suggestion or demand; I attribute it to him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Per" in this case means "according to", taken from the Latin word *per* which meant "per : (+ acc.) (cause) because of, on account of. "

The OED has a citation from 1818 where the meaning is "as laid down by (by a judge)"

The above was taken from [here](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=177973) and [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/frivs/latin/latin-dict-full.html#R)

Comment: I've always read it as "on behalf of." "According to," works most of the time, but "as laid down by," seems to translate better as "on behalf of."

Comment: "On behalf of" is usually rendered _per pro_ or _pp_, as when secretaries sign letters for their absent boss.  It actually means the reverse of that, though :-)

Comment: I agree "according to" or "as [name] said" is the meaning we're looking for: **Per Jane, we are to meet in the conference room at 2**, for example.

Comment: Alternatively, per : (+ acc.) (means / instrument) through, with, by, by means of. Namely the last, 'By means of Jane (== By way of Jane; By the way of being informed by Jane) we are to meet in the conference room at 2.' This chimes far better with the latin I studied, where the only context per made much of an appearance in was similar to 'per viam advenit' (He came through the street... if my memory fails me not)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's another very important usage of this word, one that hasn't been mentioned yet.

> The room costs 40 € per person.

In this case, *per* has a meaning for *for each*. This matches with the main question as asked in the topic title, but doesn't with the example given in the thread itself: *per John*, as you never charge something per John, haha.

There's another case where *per* would fit both your examples. Like this:

> I finished the job per John's request.

Which basically means you finished the job as John ordered you to.

Comment: I suspect most prositutes do in fact charge _per john_. ;-)